# Data from php file cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to get data from my database in my android app, but I cannot. I used [this site](https://codinginflow.com/code-examples/android/volley-json-parsing) as an example on how to parse JSON to my app. If i try to use the variable age he has on his example, my code works, but with my php, it does not. Below will be my code files.

My php. It outputs an array without a key, which I found is no problem and the data are coordinates to paint some rooms in a painter i created. Data are from user inputs, which could vary, one user could paint 5 rooms, another could have 10. [Its current output is this](https://api.myjson.com/bins/z9l5v) . This php file is working correctly on the site I use it too.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('dbconfig/config.php');
    //phpinfo();
?>
    <?php 

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM painterarrays  WHERE painterarrays.username='darf' ";
         $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {    
             $i=0; 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id=$row['id'];
        $startX= $row['startX'];
        $startY=$row['startY'];
        $endX=$row['endX'];
        $endY=$row['endY'];

        $ar[$i]=array('id'=>$id,'startX'=>$startX,'startY'=>$startY,'endX'=>$endX,'endY'=>$endY);
        $i++;
    }
        $c= json_encode($ar);
        echo $c;


  } else {
    echo "0 results";
}


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Below is the Activity of the app that should get the Json and send it to another Activity, to paint the rooms (CustomView). 
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    private RequestQueue mQueue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        jsonParse();
        setContentView(new CustomView(this));


    }


    private void jsonParse() {

        final String url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/f2kbn";
        Log.d("check before request",url.toString());
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try {
                            Log.d("check before jsonarray",url);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(url);
                            Log.d("check after jsonArray",jsonArray.toString());

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject room = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                                int id = room.getInt("id");
                                int startX = room.getInt("startX");
                                int startY = room.getInt("startY");
                                int endX = room.getInt("endX");
                                int endY = room.getInt("endY");

                               Intent yy = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CustomView.class);
                                yy.putExtra("id",id);
                                yy.putExtra("startX",startX);
                                yy.putExtra("startY",startY);
                                yy.putExtra("endX",endX);
                                yy.putExtra("endY",endY);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

And below is the error from Android Studio

```
    com.tonikamitv.loginregister D/HI BEFORE THE JSONARray: https://api.myjson.com/bins/f2kbn
    com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value https of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:112)
com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err:     at com.tonikamitv.loginregister.MuseumActivity$1.onResponse(MuseumActivity.java:48)
com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err:     at com.tonikamitv.loginregister.MuseumActivity$1.onResponse(MuseumActivity.java:43)
com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:819)
com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656)
com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

I dont think it's needed to post the CustomView.class as the app doesn't even touch that activity, considering it's stuck on the start of the request. So, any ideas?

Comment: this `..= new JSONArray(url);` should be `..= new JSONArray(response);`, right? Now you try to convert `"https://api.myjson.com/bins/f2kbn"` to a JsonArray... EDIT: not response, cause thats an JSONArray already. What Andy says!

Comment: You already have the array in parameter 'response' - use that in loop.

Comment: Sorry, still a newbie in android development. should have thought to use response. Thank you guys